# Reliably measure JVM allocations

Tags: performance, kotlin, jmh

I have two implementations of the same algorithm. I would like to verify that non of them uses more memory than necessary, or, in other words, that they allocate exactly the same number of objects.

My current solution is to measure the number of allocated bytes before and after the procedures via `threadMXBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(threadId)` and use that as an approximation of the memory footprint.

The problem is that this method is unstable, e.i. sometimes it returns a much greater number than it should. It especially shows on algorithms that don't allocate objects. One problematic example is a method that sums an `int[]`.

Actual code (Kotlin):

```
class MemAllocationTest {

    private val threadMXBean = (ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean() as? com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean)
            ?: throw RuntimeException("Runtime does not support com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean")

    /**
     * May run [block] several times
     * */
    private inline fun measureAllocatedBytes(block: () -> Unit): Long {
        val threadId = Thread.currentThread().id

        val before = threadMXBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(threadId)
        block()
        val after = threadMXBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(threadId)

        return after - before
    }

....
```

Is there a better solution?

(I don't know how to do that with JMH, but IMHO this is a very close topic)

Comment: Not directly related to question but I don't seem to understand how come `Thread.currentThread().id` could have changed after `block` execution?

Comment: @miensol good question, I guess it cannot. Edited, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMH has `-prof gc` profiler, which is supposed to be accurate with allocation profiling. Although it uses the same `ThreadMXBean` under cover, it can filter out warmup effects, and average the hiccups out over multiple `@Benchmark` invocations. The typical errors are within 0.001 byte/op there.

Comment: Can it be embedded into a unit test? (preferably without parsing a bash output)

Comment: Well, yeah, you can run JMH benchmark with JMH API, and parse out profiler result.

Comment: I was just reacting to "I understand that JMH doesn't do that" -- it does. :) But maybe for the sake of unit tests it would be better to understand the reason why your original code has hiccups. I'd say you need to filter out first few invocations of the `block()` and `ThreadMXBean` methods, so that JVM may do lazy initializations first, without profiling.

Comment: Oh, sorry about the wording, I hope now it is better. Could you please look at what I do (the other answer) to confirm that it is close to what should work. Basically I skip first few runs, then select the most common measurement.

Comment: I think picking up distribution "mode" is fine.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to collect statistics with several runs:

```
private inline fun stabiliseMeasureAllocatedBytes(block: () -> Unit): Long {
    val runs = List(7) { measureAllocatedBytes(block) }
    val results = runs.drop(2) // skip warm-up

    val counts = results.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
    val (commonResult, commonCount) = counts.entries.maxBy { (result, count) -> count }!!

    if (commonCount >= results.size / 2)
        return commonResult
    else
        throw RuntimeException("Allocation measurements vary too much: $runs")
}
```